# When should I use `Dispatchers.Unconfined` vs `EmptyCoroutineContext`?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

When is it appropriate to use [`Dispatchers.Unconfined`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-unconfined.html) vs `EmptyCoroutineContext`?

My use case is that I want to create an API for intercepting network calls. I want to provide an optional parameter to control what dispatcher the interception is executed on. For the default value of this parameter, should it be `Dispatchers.Unconfined` or `EmptyCoroutineContext`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> For the default value of this parameter, should it be Dispatchers.Unconfined or EmptyCoroutineContext?

Most of the time it is `Dispatchers.Unconfined`.

`EmptyCoroutineContext` has no elements in it, semantically it is a [null object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_object_pattern). Coroutine builders, such as [launch](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/launch.html), specify their behaviour for that case: `If the context does not have any dispatcher nor any other ContinuationInterceptor, then Dispatchers.Default is used`. Most of the time you should not use `EmptyCoroutineContext` as you don't use nulls or null objects.

`Dispatchers.Unconfined` is different: it executes coroutine immediately on the current thread and later resumes it in whatever thread called `resume`.
It is usually a good fit for things like intercepting regular non-suspending API or invoking coroutine-related code from blocking world callbacks.

Comment: Thanks! I use `Dispatchers.Unconfined` often for testing purposes